# Filter code Test with real time java app

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I have created filter function in java servlet and it's working correctly.

But i need to test my filter code with real time java app, so can any one suggest me basic real time app in java in which i can add my filter command and test with it either my code is run in real time system or not.

Thanks.

Comment: Filters are meant for Java web only so, not sure what you mean by "*real time Java app*".

Comment: means specifically my code is working but need some suggestion for more test with real time java app on which i can test more in details about my code.

Comment: The term "*real time*" is not understandable in this context. In reality, it means something which is completely different.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to deploy your code on some server like tomcat, fire requests, then only you will be able to do 'real' testing.

Comment: as i said my code is locally working fine but need to more test with real time java app so need some basic suggestion for it. Thanks